# QCompleter frozen in QLineEdit in the second dialog when click the popup item in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qdialog, qcompleter

The PYQT5 demo will show a modal custom QDialog window when a button on a QMainWindow is clicked.The QDialog has a QLineEdit with QCompleter.Key Down&Up is available for selecting a popup item, but I can not use mouse to click and select it because the popup view is frozen.I also wanna the popup item text will not add to the QLineEdit automatically when use key Down&Up,only if I use mouse to click the item.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QDialog, QLineEdit, QCompleter

items_list = ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'Albert Einstein', 'Alfred E Newman']


class SecondDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SecondDialog, self).__init__()
        self.v_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.my_edit = QLineEdit()
        self.completer = QCompleter(items_list)
        self.my_edit.setCompleter(self.completer)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.my_edit)
        self.setLayout(self.v_layout)

class MyWindows(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindows, self).__init__()
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.v_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.my_btn = QPushButton("Open second Dialog")
        self.my_btn.clicked.connect(self.openDialog)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.my_btn)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

    def openDialog(self):
        d = SecondDialog()
        d.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   w = MyWindows()
   w.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: mmm, could you give a detailed procedure to reproduce the "freeze", what do you mean by "freeze"? You could point out the characteristics of your environment: OS, python version, pyqt5 version, etc. I have tested python 3.8 and PyQt5 5.15 on Linux and do not observe any freezes.

Comment: @eyllanesc I use MacBook pro 10.15.5/ Python 3.8/ PyQt5 5.15.0."freeze" means I input "J" character to the QLineEdit, the popup view will appear two items('John Doe', 'Jane Doe'),but I can not click these two items use mouse.

Comment: I observe no problem, exactly as eyllanesc. The code works as you expect it to.

Comment: @TilmanK I test on windows 10, the code really works as I expect it to.However, the same problem is still exist when I run the code on MacOS Catalina 10.15.5.